# How do I format the date to include the week number?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, bids

I am using Microsoft Business Intelligence Development Studio 2012 trying to create a calculated field that will give me the Month and Week number of a field with the name 'createdon'.

I am new to SQL and after some research this is the code that I have come up with.

```
=Format(Fields!createdon.Value, "MMMM") & " Week " & (Int(DateDiff("d",DateSerial(Year(Fields!createdon.Value),Month(Fields!createdon.Value),1), Fields!FullDateAlternateKey.Value)/7)+1).ToString
```

But I am getting the error:

> "The Field expression for the dataset 'Dataset1' refers to the field
>   'FullDateAlternateKey'. Report item expressions can only refer to
>   fields within the current datasetscop or, if inside an aggregate, the
>   specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields my use the
>   correct case.

I know this means that "FullDateAlternateKey" is not a valid field name, but I do not know what field name to substitute instead to correct this expression. Does anyone with more experience have any ideas as to how I can correct this?

Ideally, I would like it formatted to have a column that shows "week ending in ". 
So any dates from  9/26/2015 to 10/2/2015 would say "Week of 10/2/2015"

Comment: Why not use Datepart("w",Createdon.value) to return the week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
="Month: " & Datepart("m", Fields!createdon.Value) & " Week: " &
Datepart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Fields!createdon.Value)
```

You will get the following: `Month: 10 Week: 43`

Edit your question and add a example of the desired result in order to help you with the specific format.

**Update:**

Try this:

```
="Today: " & Format(Fields!createdon.Value,"dd/M/yyyy") & "Week Of: " & Format(
DATEADD("d" ,7-DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay,Fields!createdon.Value,FirstDayOfWeek.Monday),Fields!createdon.Value),
"dd/M/yyyy")
```

It will show: `Today: 19/10/2015 Week Of: 25/10/2015`